Do you have sharpened senses when you're hungry?
I'm curious if longer periods of hunger lead to a heightened acuity of your senses, especially hearing, which I suspect noticing in myself.
Googling for it mainly revealed "listen to your gut"-type of blog articles, but I did find one blog post that mentions

I had my earphones in a few evenings ago (which, I should add, are noise cancelling and really do the job!) while fasting, and I felt as though every chord, synth and lyric were infinitely clearer. It’s left me speculating about whether, by not feeding one of your senses (in this case, taste), you can sharpen another sense and strengthen it in that moment. They say that’s why a cinematic experience is best in total darkness, because your senses are stimulated and acutely refined.

So there is at least one other person that makes this claim / had hypothesized it at one point.
From an evolutionary perspective I think it'd make sense to increase sensorial input in order to be able to find food easier, when you're getting lower on energy.
Have any studies been made on this theory / is there any merit to it?

I think you need to look into anorexigenic and orexigenic neuropeptids, like AgRP, NPY vs POMC/CART. And the genetic regulatory networks that keep together the body energy intake and out-take. These neuropeptids regulate the activity in mammals and hunger or satiety does have an effect on their proportions in different regions of our body, therefore making  us more active when hungry and less when satiated. I think that this seems like ongoing research and the role of all the involved elements is not fully understood.
